# Text tagging/analysis tool for Mac

Tags: macos, text, analysis, tagging

I'm a doctoral student doing research in the humanities. As part of my research I have gathered together a lot of interview text. To analyse this data I want to be able to easily tag sections of text with keywords (the tags need to be able to overlap, and perhaps be organised hierarchically) and later be able to collate those sections from across multiple files. I need to be able to do this on a Mac.

It feels like a simple task but I can't find any software for doing it that isn't either horribly clunky or a massive overkill worth hundreds of pounds. Is there any good software for doing this, or are there any good ways of doing it with other software?

Comment: This is what databases are for.

Comment: Stack Overflow is dedicated to programming questions, your question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: sorry, I didn't realise the site was that specifically targeted. I'll head over there.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I suggest you RQDA. I've done tutorials video in french and english about this free software working on all plateforms :

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL66CB2FF65368715C&feature=plcp